# Current Status of RED GUI and VIEW

Tags: red

Which is the current status of the RED GUI ? Are listviews already available ?

Which STYLES are still missing ?

How many people are working on IT ?

Is there an android version ?

Comment: I don't think your question is adequate for SO, as it's meant to be obsolete very quickly, and could be repeated _ad infinitum_ every month... SO help says: _"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."_ You should better ask your question on the Red ML or chat room at http://gitter.im/red/red

Comment: Thanks Doc, it is first time using SO, failing the first time in something should be a good way to success :-)

Comment: No worries, see you in Red channels. ;-)